# Is a large change in radon test results normal?

Tags: radon

I am selling my home in Georgia and just had a Radon test result of 7.0 as part of the buyer's inspection. When I moved in 10 years ago the test result was only .9. Is this much change normal or should I question the result?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the test re-done, they generally aren't very expensive, but avoid the home testing kits, they aren't as reliable, and any buyer will probably have the test done themselves anyway professionally. It is a significant jump, it definitely crosses the threshold of "safe" and "needs correction". Any smart buyer will want you to correct a value this high, too. A test result >= 4 pCi/L warrants some kind of radon abatement [according the the EPA](http://www.epa.gov/radon/pubs/citguide.html).